# Trigonometry Olympiad Question

Tags: trigonometry

Given $x, y$ are acute angles such that $\sin y= 3\cos(x+y)\sin x$. Find the maximum value of $\tan y$.

Attempt at a solution:

$[sin y = 3(cos x cos y - sin x sin y) sin x] 1/cos y$

$tan y = (3 cos x - 3 sin x tan y) sin x$

$tan y + 3 sin^2 x + tan y = 3 sin x cos x$

$tan y = (3 sin x cos x) / (1 + 3 sin x)$

I'm stuck here...

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655203/given-x-y-are-acute-angles-such-that-sin-y-3-cosxy-sin-x-find-the-max

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides by $\cos y$

$$\tan y=3\sin x(\cos x-\sin x\tan y)$$

Divide both sides by $\cos^2x$

$$3\tan x-(3\tan y)\tan^2x=\tan y(1+\tan^2x)$$

$$\iff\tan^2x(4\tan y)-3\tan x+\tan y=0$$

As $\tan x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$