# Given $x, y$ are acute angles such that $\sin y= 3\cos(x+y)\sin x$. Find the maximum value of $\tan y$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given $x, y$ are acute angles such that $\sin y= 3\cos(x+y)\sin x$. Find the maximum value of $\tan y$.

Attempt at a solution:

$$(\sin y = 3(\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y) \sin x) \frac{1}{\cos y}$$

$$\tan y = (3 \cos x - 3 \sin x \tan y) \sin x$$

$$\tan y + 3 \sin^2 x + \tan y = 3 \sin x \cos x$$

$$\tan y = \frac{3 \sin x \cos x}{1 + 3 \sin^2 x}$$

I have also tried substituting $0$, $30$, $45$, $60$, $90$ to the values of $x$.

Comment: i have got an other formula for $\tan(y)$

Comment: You're almost there. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo. It must be $$\tan y=\dfrac{3\sin x\cos x}{1+3\sin^2 x}=\dfrac{3\sin 2x}{5-3\cos 2x}$$for minimizing it we should have the 1st-order derivation of $\tan y$ equal to $0$ or $$\dfrac{d\tan y}{dx}=0$$which yields to $$6\cos 2x(5-3\cos 2x)=6\sin 2x\cdot 3\sin 2x$$which yields to $\cos 2x=\dfrac{3}{5}$ and $\sin 2x=\dfrac{4}{5}$. Substituting these values in the expression of $\tan y$ we attain the maximum:$$\max_{0\le x\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \tan y=\dfrac{3}{4}$$

Here is a sketch of $\tan y$ respect to $x$
[image]

Comment: Why is the whole equation not differentiated?

Comment: Which equation you mean? I have differentiated whole $\tan y$ respect to $x$

Comment: 6cos2x(5−3cos2x)=6sin2x⋅3sin2x
So this means that there is no need to solve for the denominator since our goal is to make the numerator equal to 0. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let's play.

$\sin y
= 3\cos(x+y)\sin x
= 3(\cos x \cos y-\sin x \sin y)\sin x
$

Divide by
$\cos x \cos y$

$\dfrac{\tan y}{\cos x}
= 3(\cos x -\sin x \tan y)\tan x
= 3\cos x\tan x -3\sin x\tan x \tan y
$

$\tan y(\dfrac{1}{\cos x}+3\sin x\tan x)
= 3\cos x\tan x
=3\sin x
$

$\tan y(1+3\sin^2 x)
=3\sin x\cos x
$

$\tan y
=\dfrac{3\sin x\cos x}{1+3\sin^2 x}
=\dfrac{\frac32\sin(2 x)}{1+3(1-\cos(2x))/2}
=\dfrac{3\sin(2 x)}{2+3(1-\cos(2x))}
=\dfrac{3\sin(2 x)}{5-3\cos(2x)}
$

At this point,
it being about midnight here,
I threw this at Wolfy
which said that
its max value was
$\dfrac34$
at
$\pi n +\arctan(1/2)$.

So the max value is
$\dfrac34$.

Comment: I got it until the part of tan y = (3 sin x cos x) / (1+ 3sin^2 x)
Could you please explain how you got sin (2 x) ?

Comment: @Janjan $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$. You can see this by, for instance, considering $e^{2i x} = (e^{i x})^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from marty cohen's answer
$$\tan (y)=\dfrac{3\sin(2 x)}{5-3\cos(2x)}$$ let $t=\tan(x)$ to get 
$$\tan (y)=\frac{3 t}{4 t^2+1}=f(t)$$ So 
$$f'(t)=\frac{3-12 t^2}{\left(4 t^2+1\right)^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(t)=\frac{24 t \left(4 t^2-3\right)}{\left(4 t^2+1\right)^3}$$ The first derivative cancels for $t_{\pm}=\pm \frac 12$. For $t_+$, $f''(t+)=-3$ corresponding to a maximum and for $t_-$,  $f''(t_-)=3$ corresponding to a minimum.

So, $t=\frac 12$ and $\tan(y)=\frac34$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(y)
&=3\cos(x+y)\sin(x)\\
&=3\cos(x)\cos(y)\sin(x)-3\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(x)
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(y)
&=\frac{3\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1+3\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\frac{3\tan(x)}{\sec^2(x)+3\tan^2(x)}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{3\tan(x)}{1+4\tan^2(x)}
\end{align}
$$
Then note that $1+4\tan^2(x)=4\tan(x)+(2\tan(x)-1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I start, like everyone else with $3\sin2x/(5-3\cos2x)$.

Consider a circle, radius 3, around 5+0i in the complex plane.  The highest value for tan y is for the line through the origin, tangent to the circle.  That forms a 3-4-5 right-angled triangle, so $\tan y=3/4$.